# Prime Numbers programming

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to write this program to test and output all prime numbers in a range given by the user. I posted this code before, but I have a different problem now. Right now, it mostly works except that when the outputs are in the single digits, then it won't output as I want, but anything past that, it will output everything correctly as far I can tell. I also had the inside if written as `if (start % div == 0 || start % 3 == 0)`, which also let single digits primes (except 2) print out, but then higher number non-primes, starting at 49 I think, started to output.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int first, second;                                      
bool notPrime = true;                                   

cout << "Please enter the first number: ";              
cin >> first;
cout << "Please enter the second number: ";             
cin >> second;
cout << "The prime numbers between " << first << " and " << second << " are: ";

if (first < second)                                 
{
    for (int start = first; start <= second; start++)
    {
        for (int div = 2; div < start; div++)
        {
            if (start % div == 0 || start % 3 == 0 || start % 5 == 0 || start % 7 == 0)
                break;
            else if (start % div != 0)
                {
                cout << start << " ";
                break;
                }
        }
    }
}
_getch();
return 0;
}
```

So this is what I have right now. The only outputs I'm getting now though, are 1 and 2, and 1 doesn't count as a prime number.

```
if (first < second)                                 
{
    for (testNumber = first; testNumber <= second; ++testNumber)
    {
        bool prime (testNumber);
        for (int div = 2; div <= testNumber; ++div)
        {
            if (testNumber <= 1)
            {
                prime = false;
                break;
            }
            else if (testNumber == 2)
            {
                prime = true; 
                break;
            }
            else if (testNumber % div == 0)
            {
                prime = false;
            }
        }
        if (prime)
        {
            cout << testNumber << " ";      
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Your logic is wrong; this can't be fixed. Notice that you explicitly exclude certain primes, and that `div` never takes any value except 2. I suggest you try something simpler.

Comment: You need to have the program *remember* valid primes and use them to check numbers.  For example, your program doesn't use 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, etc.  Are you going to put each one in your `if` statement?

Comment: So, could I use the `bool notPrime = true` in a way that can change the logic? Also, how do I make my program remember valid primes?

Answer (score 1):

Your algorhitm is just wrong. The easiest, unoptimized algorithm is: take the number that you want to test (in your case, `start` - by the way, I'd call it something like `number_to_test` instead) and divide it modulo 2, then modulo 3, 4, 5, and so on (if you want to make it faster, first try dividing by 2 and then try only the odd numbers starting from 3, which is what I think you are trying to do). Every time, check the result: if it is 0 it means the number can be divided by something and is not prime.

What you are doing with this line

```
if (start % div == 0 || start % 3 == 0 || start % 5 == 0 || start % 7 == 0)
```

is checking, for every possible value of `div`, whether `start` can be divided either by: `div` (which is ok), 3, 5, 7. Why these 3 numbers? Why are you testing them every time? You don't need to do that. The division by 3, 5 and 7 will be checked when `div` reaches those values. Anyway, if any of these divisions has rest 0, you break from the loop, that is, you stop verifying `start`, because you have already found out that it is not prime. So far, this first `if` that checks 4 conditions is doing something that is not needed (that is, the last 3 conditions are not needed), but it doesn't really harm.

But then comes the error: if the previous `if` failed, you have a further check, which is `if (start % div != 0)`, which is guaranteed to succeed: this condition *must* be true, otherwise the code wouldn't have reached the `else`. So, your `else if` is actually a simple `else`. And what happens then? You print the number, as if it were prime, and you `break`, which means you are finished with that number. But it isn't necessarily prime! All you know so far is that it can't be divided by `div` (that is, 2), 3, 5, 7. You haven't checked any divisors beyond 7! For example, try to run your program from 120 to 122. It shouldn't find any primes, but it considers 121 prime. It isn't (it's 11*11), but your program doesn't test division by 11!

To fix the error you must decide that `start` is prime only at the end of the loop, if no divisor has been found so far. There's a small problem: in *any* case you will reach the end of the loop, either because you have found a divisor (and then you call `break;`), or because you haven't found any, and you have simply completed the loop until the end. Then, how can you know whether a prime was found or not? You can introduce a new variable, `bool prime;` for this purpose. You must set it to `true`, by default, at the start of the inner loop; if you find a divisor, set it to `false`, just before breaking. By doing this, at the end you can check it: if it is still `true`, you know you have found no divisor, and you can print your prime number. If it is `false`, it means there was at least a divisor, and you don't print it.

```
bool prime = true;
for (int div = 2; div < start; div++)
{
    if (start % div == 0) {
        prime = false;
        break;
    }
}
if (prime) {
    cout << start << " ";
}
```

This is a very simple implementation. It can be greatly optimized, but I'd say you should concentrate on making the simple case work before you introduce any changes.